# Recommended merge policies on main context & private context in multi-threaded CoreData app

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, merge

I've read and tried to understand the recommended praxis of doing this, but I would like to have Your expert opinions on the following scenario;

I use CoreData and have a main context assigned to the persistent store coordinator.

```
- (void) setupCoreDataStack
{
    self.managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSBundle allBundles]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

    NSURL *url = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model.sqlite"];

    NSDictionary *options = @{NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionComplete,
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES};
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:options error:&error];
    if (!store)
    {
        NSError *deleteError = nil;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&deleteError])
        {
            error = nil;
            store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:options error:&error];
        }

        if (!store)
        {
            // Also inform the user...
            NSLog(@"Failed to create persistent store. Error %@. Delete error %@",error,deleteError);
            abort();
        }
    }

    self.mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.mainManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
}
```

All my async worked threads (sync with backend, perform various BLE/CoreBluetooth actives, etc) create their own private contexts (from within their async dispatched threads), and then use *performBlock* to perform the work before finally saving private context AND main context according to guidelines/recommendations;

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void)
{
    //Create private context and lnk to main context..
    NSManagedObjectContext* privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

    //Link private context to main context...
    privateContext.parentContext = self.mainManagedObjectContext;

    //Perform login-mechanism in block
    [privateContext performBlock:^{

        //Do the work!
        ...
        ...

        //Merge changes to main context!
        NSError* error = nil;
        if (![privateContext save:&error])
            abort();

        //Save main context to persistent store coordinator
        [self.mainManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{

            NSError *mainError;
            if (![self.mainManagedObjectContext save:&mainError])
                abort();
        }];
    }];
});
```

My question now is, how does the merge policies work in this setup? When I assign the mainContext a mergePolicy, does that apply to how changes are merged from mainContext to PSC, or when private contexts are merged to main context?

Is my understanding correct, that using *NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy* in this setup, if assigned to the private contexts, will ensure that the private context changes are merged to main context and that the private object will be used if there's a conflict? Or do I have to set the main context's mergePolicy of this to work too?

Thank you for your thoughts,
/Markus

Answer (score 4):

Generally you want to set the merge policy on the main `NSManagedObjectContext`.  However my first question is, are you getting merge conflicts?  If you are not getting any then do you need to change the merge policy at all?

I tend to leave the default policy (error on merge) in place until I actually hit a merge problem.  Otherwise you could be potentially masking a problem by the merge working when you didn't realize there was a merge situation.

Comment: I had them left out originally, but had to define some value when I got a conflict. Honestly, I don't know if that conflict is still present though due to some code-polishing that I've been doing so that's a good test, really. I posted this question more on a conceptual basis, looking for guidelines given that I a) never change the model/data from main-thread (only reading from UI), and b) have multiple possibly simultaneous async threads with private contexts (requesting data from backend, updating state due to BLE-activities, synchronizing changes made when app was offline).

Comment: a quick test and guess what; no need to merge policy (at the moment) since I have no conflict and everything works like it should. That said, I'm still curious and would like to understand things once and for all; if I see a conflict, then obviously I need to look at *where* that conflict is (e.g., merge from private to main-context, or main to PSC), and set the merge policy accordingly. Or, are you suggesting that a private context *don't* need a merge policy, ever?

Comment: Children that just write don't need a merge policy.  Only the context that they are pushing to (the parent) needs its.  They never have a merge conflict because they are only reading from a single source.  The main context can have a conflict because a user and/or other children can alter data at the same time.  That is **IF** you run into a problem in the first place.

Comment: Understood - and makes sense. I have one more follow-up though; I was a bit too quick yesterday when I said no conflict, as I later crashed due to a CoreData merge conflict. But, the objects had the exact same contents, but with different versions (one had 3 the other 4), but this number is not set by me. I suspect that it's an auto-generated version that just increment each time I create classes from my CoreData model entities? And, if so -- what's the recommendation for managing revisions in entity changes? One way is obviously to set `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`...

Comment: Clarification of above comment by myself; I mean, I know that I haven't changed the entity's structure (attributes/relationships), but I sure have generated new classes when I did changes in a different entity (just to be on the safe-side). Ideally, I'd prefer to NOT use the mergePolicy (since there's no data changes, only version numbers), and manually control the version for each entity as I know when I change an entity's structure...?

Comment: Setting the merge policy is an application level decision.  If your application wants the information from the server to be the truth then `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` makes sense.  If you want the local store to be the truth then `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType` might make more sense.  In either case you want to set that merge policy on the main `NSManagedObjectContext`.